# Are there any compatibility with IE Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Sencha there any compatibility with Internet Explorer, I'm trying to visualize my application in the Microsoft browser. Do I have to change any file for viewing Sencha my application? Please help with this.

I'm using Sencha Touch 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-touch-2)

> Sencha Touch is a framework based on modern technologies like CSS3,
>   JavaScript, and HTML5. There are browsers that do not support
>   HTML5/CSS3 at all or support it rudimentarily. Internet Explorer still
>   is the most retarded browser in existance, also with respect to HTML5.
>   It’s not Sencha Touch that fails to support IE , it’s just that IE
>   does not really support HTML5, at least not any IE version before
>   IE10.

Comment: `Internet Explorer still is the most retarded browser in existance` - awesomness :)

Answer (score 0):

best sencha results i've had have been in google chrome, plus the console in chrome is very helpful.  on a side note, I don't know what you are working on but sencha 2.0 is so much more advanced, it's worth making the leap.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch (2.2) will support Windows Phone 8.

Currently 2.2 is still beta. Apparently the GA release has been expected for a while.

[Sencha Touch with windows Phone 8](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-with-windows-phone-8/)

(Check comments for some clarification of details)